# Digital signature on PDF - Complete certificate chain does not show in acrobat reader using Itextsharp 5 .net

Tags: c#, itext

Digital signature on PDF - Complete certificate chain does not show in Acrobat reader DC using Itextsharp 5 with .net
On FOXIT reader certificate complete chain is showing.

PDF download Link : [PDF_SAMPLE](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g34e8d7e3c9f6f1e7100008630003121642a8562831)

```
private void SignWithCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            ICollection<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
            X509Chain x509chain = new X509Chain();
            x509chain.Build(cert);

            foreach (X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509chain.ChainElements)
            {
                chain.Add(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate));
            }

            IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-256");
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(_sourceFile);
            FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(_targetFile, FileMode.Create);  //the output pdf file
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0');
            PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
            //here set signatureAppearance at your will
            signatureAppearance.Reason = _reason;
            signatureAppearance.Location = _location;
signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
            signatureAppearance.Acro6Layers = true;
            signatureAppearance.Layer4Text = "";
signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(_coordinates), _pageNo, "Sig");
            MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
        }
```

Comment: Please share a sample signed PDF to analyze.

Comment: Please download signed pdf on above Link.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that *"Complete certificate chain does not show in Acrobat reader DC"*, cf. [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGbLK.png) from Adobe Acrobat Reader DC..

Comment: And the chain indeed is embedded, I just checked by analyzing an ASN.1 dump of the signature container.

Comment: Actually Certificate chain has four values but when I check in Acrobat reader it shows only two path. Root path is missing. But in code all four is embedded in chain[ ] .

Comment: Cf. [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGbLK.png) of an Acrobat Reader dialog, it also shows 4 certificates. Have you probably added an intermediate certificate to your trust store? That would explain it, there would be no need for Acrobat Reader to show any certificates beyond a trusted one.

Comment: Please once check in Adobe Reader XI.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Adobe Reader XI installed anymore.